Need to create employee roster on excel - when number of logins at a particular hour is provided for each day
I have a peculiar problem where despite being moderately good with Excel, I am stuck.
I have figured out number of logins required on each day of the week at different hours basis my demand pattern. The table is similar to below.
Please note that there are three types of shifts - First who work a long shift (say 9 hrs), Second who work a relatively shorter shift (say 6 hrs) and finally who work a split shift of 4/5 hours (Split shift timings are fixed - 9 am to 1 PM and 7 PM to 12 midnight).
The requirement of logins is something as specified in below table:



Shift Type
Hour
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday




Split Shift
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


Split Shift
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


Split Shift
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


Split Shift
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Split Shift
9
4
4
3
4
5
5
6


.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Split Shift
23
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


Shift A
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


Shift A
1
0
0
2
2
1
1
1


Shift A
2
3
2
1
1
1
0
2


Shift A
3
0
4
0
0
1
0
1


.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Shift A
23
0
1
0
0
1
0
0


Shift B
0
0
1
0
4
0
6
0


Shift B
1
1
0
1
1
4
0
7


Shift B
1
0
3
0
2
0
1
3


.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Shift B
23
0
1
0
0
2
0
2



Now with this data, I need to create an employee roster similar to below table:



Week Off Day
Shift Type
Emp No
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday




Wednesday
Split Shift
1
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Tuesday
Split Shift
2
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Monday
Split Shift
3
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Tuesday
Split Shift
4
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Thursday
Split Shift
5
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Wednesday
Shift A
6
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Wednesday
Shift A
7
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Tuesday
Shift A
8
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Wednesday
Shift A
9
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Thursday
Shift B
10
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


Wednesday
Shift B
11
.
.
.
.
.
.
.



The only constraint with above table is I am free to decide which day to give as week off except Saturday and Sunday (Those are high sale days). So, in above table, I am calculating it using (=IF(B10="","",CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5),"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"))
Also, the count of employees for each shift is equal to max shift count on any day given by first table. For eg. If Shift A has highest logins of 15 on Sunday, I have 15 rows for shift A in above table. I am able to get this by (=LAMBDA(values,num_repeat, XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(num_repeat)),VSTACK(1,SCAN(1,num_repeat,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))),VSTACK(values,""),,-1))(B4:B7,C4:C7)) where B4:B7 are different shift types and C4:C7 is Max value for any particular day for that shift type.
The only thing left is to fill in the timings at which the supposed Emp 1 has to login into the system on each day.
Please note that each employee need not login at same time into the system, hence I am trying to look at logins required from 0 to 23 hours and allocate one by one to each employee.
Also, the shift type for each employee is fixed. An employee cannot work both split shift and Shift A in same week.

Posted a couple of answers on here that you will find relevant using the Solver.
